# how to set base context url for different request url

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have been trying to fix for days, but no fix yet, i want to have fix base url with root context , rest of the url string will change, but my base url should be fixed for each request.

here is scenario,

in a home page, when user clicks "Login" it will call menu controller and the request url will be as below

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/menu/login.jsp
```

once my login page loads, when i do "Sing in", the url should be as below

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/singIn.jsp
```

but above was not working and my url request is some thing like

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/menu/user/singIn.jsp
```

so it was taking relative path instead of absolute, i have code below code added to my layout jsp to fix this problem to have base url fixed, but it is not working.

```
<base href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}">
```

above code i have added to layout.jsp which contains header, body and footer, and my request presents in body jsp.

Edit :- the request are jquery ajax request

Answer (score 0):

use `<base href="${pageContext.contextPath}">`

instead of

```
<base href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}">
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%String path = request.getContextPath();

String basePath=request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
`

```
<base href="<%=basePath%>">
```